# Can't run Jekyll on Mac OS 12

Tags: jekyll, macos-monterey

I've had problems running Jekyll since updating to Monterey. So I did a clean install but the problems remain. I carefully followed the tutorial from jekyllrb.com to install ruby and Jekyll.

When I try to run the local server from a website I created with Jekyll before OS12 (and which still runs perfectly well on a Mac with OS11), I get this:

```
Could not find addressable-2.7.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

And if I do run 'bundle install' this does not solve the problem. I get the same error message again and again, as if it were looking for the script in the wrong location. So, is there a specific working directory I need to run this install command from? Is it a PATH problem?

When I try to create a website from scratch following the tutorial from jekyllrb.com :

```
Jekyll create mywebsite
cd mywebsite
bundle exec Jekyll serve
```

I get this:

```
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll)

/Users/stephane/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
```

Now, is this a PATH issue?

Here's my PATH:

```
stephane@Stephanes-iMac ~ % echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"
/Users/stephane/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Thank you very much for any help you could give me :)

Stephane

Comment: Without knowing how you installed Ruby on the two different computers and what's different between them, it's hard to provide specific advice. If you can share the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` of the site that's giving you the `Could not find addressable-2.7.0` error, I can try it on macOS 12 and see if it works for me.

Can you also post the result of `gem env` from each computer?

In the meantime, you can try this script I wrote that will reliably [install Ruby on Mac](https://www.rubyonmac.dev/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=69918091).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and saw this: https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/load-error-cannot-load-such-file-webrick/5417/2

I did `bundle add webrick` and that one worked for me

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps. I can get Jekyll to run with a website I start from scratch. However, for those I need to maintain it makes no difference. Besides, if I create a blog on OS12 it seems I cannot run it from a Mac on OS11. And I'm used to working from two different computers. Such a headache!

Comment: glad I could help! I went through the same problem as well. One more thing is checking here https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/ does not look like you have problems with path but maybe can still verify the path variables are set up correctly